# python lxml get parent element when you know child text with xpath

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml

I have the following xml file: *test.xml*

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <SubmitTransaction xmlns="http://www.someaddress.com/someendpoint">
      <objTransaction>
        <DataFields>
          <TxnField>
            <FieldName>Pickup.Address.CountryCode</FieldName>
            <FieldValue>DE</FieldValue>
            <FieldIndex>0</FieldIndex>
          </TxnField>
          <TxnField>
            <FieldName>Pickup.Address.PostalCode</FieldName>
            <FieldValue>10827</FieldValue>
            <FieldIndex>0</FieldIndex>
          </TxnField>
          <TxnField>
            <FieldName>Pickup.DateTime</FieldName>
            <FieldValue>2016-05-28T03:26:05</FieldValue>
            <FieldIndex>0</FieldIndex>
          </TxnField>
          <TxnField>
            <FieldName>Pickup.LocationTypeCode</FieldName>
            <FieldValue>O</FieldValue>
            <FieldIndex>0</FieldIndex>
          </TxnField>
          <TxnField>
            <FieldName>Pickup.Address.City</FieldName>
            <FieldValue>Berlin</FieldValue>
            <FieldIndex>0</FieldIndex>
          </TxnField>
        </DataFields>
      </objTransaction>
    </SubmitTransaction>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

What I want to do is to get an element with tag `TxnField` that has a child `FieldName` with text `Pickup.DateTime`. It is important to get the parent element, so I need to get this:

```
<TxnField>
  <FieldName>Pickup.DateTime</FieldName>
  <FieldValue>2016-05-28T03:26:05</FieldValue>
  <FieldIndex>0</FieldIndex>
</TxnField>
```

What I have so far is the following:

```
from lxml import etree
xml_parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)
xml_tree = etree.parse('test.xml', xml_parser)

p_time = xml_tree.xpath("//*[local-name()='TxnField']/*[text()='Pickup.DateTime']")
print(p_time[0].tag) # {http://http://www.someaddress.com/someendpoint}FieldName
```

But this gives me the actual element with text `Pickup.DateTime` and I am interested in getting its parent as shown above.

**As a side note**: it took me almost an hour even to get this far because I find the lxml documentation to be very cumbersome. If anyone has a link with a good tutorial please post it at least as a comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Here is a suggestion:

```
from lxml import etree

NSMAP = {"s": "http://www.someaddress.com/someendpoint"}

xml_parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)
xml_tree = etree.parse('test.xml', xml_parser)

p_time = xml_tree.xpath("//s:FieldName[.='Pickup.DateTime']", namespaces=NSMAP)[0]
parent = p_time.getparent()
```

- The `s` prefix is declared to be bound to the `http://www.someaddress.com/someendpoint` namespace. It is used in the XPath expression instead of `local-name()`.
- The call to `xpath()` returns a list with one item (the wanted `FieldName` element) and then the `getparent()` method is used to find its parent.

There is more than one way to do it!

Btw, I think this is a pretty good lxml tutorial: http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/pylxml/web/index.html

Comment: Thanks, the thing is I want to make it ignore the namespaces. Does your solution work without it?

Comment: This also works: `p_time = xml_tree.xpath("//*[local-name() = 'FieldName'][.='Pickup.DateTime']")[0]`

Comment: I deliberately declared a namespace prefix and used it because you did not, and I wanted my answer to show a different approach.

Answer (score 3):

I have found how to get it:

```py
p_time = xml_tree.xpath("//*[local-name()='TxnField']/*[text()='Pickup.DateTime']/./..")
```

Answer (score 1):

Preferable XPath expression, IMHO, to get parent node having child node with certain value is something like this:

```
//d:TxnField[d:FieldName='Pickup.DateTime']
```

the above assumed that you have mapped prefix `d` to the default namespace URI. But from your comments, seems like you prefer to ignore namespaces here, so this is the equivalent expression without having to have registered namespace prefix:

```
//*[local-name()='TxnField'][*[local-name()='FieldName' and .='Pickup.DateTime']]
```